# File upload/download package?

Tags: files, upload

Can anyone recommend a package I can install that will create a website on my Ubuntu server that can act like an upload/download site. I appreciate there are lots of options available that can run from an existing Apache or nginx install but I'm looking for something that is as 'self contained' as possible with the port being configurable. Basically the HTTP equivalent of a self contained FTP service.

Thanks

Comment: Investigate Filezilla https://filezilla-project.org/ it is available via your Synaptic Package Manager. Could be an interesting project.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option might be to enable webdav on your server.  There is a reasonable guide for this here:
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-webdav-on-your-ubuntu-server/

For something a bit more comprehensive, you might want to consider NextCloud:
https://nextcloud.com/

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I eventually settled on a docker nginx-webdav image.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually settled on the following docker image: xama/nginx-webdav

```
docker run --restart always -d \
           -e WEBDAV_USERNAME=admin \
           -e WEBDAV_PASSWORD=admin \
           -p 8080:80 \
           -v /path/to/your/files:/var/webdav/public \
           xama/nginx-webdav
```